# Query dimension in Star Schema

Tags: data-warehouse, star-schema

During report creation, I've included data from only dimensions (no measures), and records from them are cross joined. Can you query only dimensions from the Star Schema in a report? For example in the following simple SSAS cube, can I query Subject and Student to see how many students were there per course?:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a example of a query you are trying to make? The answer to your question depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I've added more explanation if that helps...

Comment: That helps. I'll post a suggestion on weekend

Comment: Did you get time for this?

Comment: Nancy - is it possible for the students to be enrolled into a course but have no score (i.e, they are absent from the fact table)?

Comment: It is possible. But, in this case I have assumed that everyone has score.